# Is there any mean to render an object in a React div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

Currently my console returns to me:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name,
>   age, cool}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
>   array instead

It would be interesting for interactivity if render object directly on DOM as is it rendered on console could be possible,

any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: JSON.stringify(object)

Comment: Technically object is a data structure in memory, it doesn't make any sense to render it. You can render JSON representation of it like: `<pre>{JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)}</pre>`

Comment: A component can’t render object/objects

Answer (score 1):

A generic way to achieve it with any kind of object could be to use `Object.entries` :

```js
const myObject = {
    age: 15,
    length: 157,
    pigeons: "CROAH",
    something: 'oeirjgoerijgmqeoij'
}


const App = props => (
    <div>
        {Object.entries(myObject).map(([key, value]) =>
            <p>{key} : {value}</p>
        )}
    </div>
)


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

You can make the component accept an object in its props and use it anywhere to render your objects later on.

There is no way to get the same result as you would get in your console, unless you wan to remake it by yourself.

Comment: thanks :), effectively I talked about the console way, thnanks for the hints

Comment: Alright. Consoles are browser specific, and are totally independent to the main window, React does not know which browser you are using, unless you can find an NPM package capable of copying one

Answer (score 1):

In order to get it **exactly** like the console, that is

```
{
  name: "Homer Jay",
  age: 38,
  phrase: "DO'H!!!"
}
```

Use a preformatted text tag `<pre>` and `JSON.stringify()`, like this:

```js
render() {
  return <pre>
    {JSON.stringify(myObject, null, 2)}
  </pre>
}
```

Here you can read more about it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

Directly, no, but you could use a `for...in` loop to iterate over the object properties and render their values that way.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 0):

you can just output it one key at a time, i.e.

```
<p>{yourObject.name}</p>
<p>{yourObject.age}</p>
<p>{yourObject.cool}</p>
```

If you have an array of these objects, you could wrap that in a div and make it the return in a map() function like this:

```
{
yourArray.map(yourObject => (
  <div key={yourObject.name}>
    <p>{yourObject.name}</p>
    <p>{yourObject.age}</p>
    <p>{yourObject.cool}</p>
  </div>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can render object of type array , so if these object keys are of type array you can directly type them inside div to render them.

```
let array = ['name','age','class']
 render(){

    return(
       <div>
         array
        </div> 
       )
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to render an array of objects in `React` is to loop through it and render each object and its properties inside a div.

```js
yourArray.map(yourObject => (
  <div key={yourObject.id}>
    <p>{yourObject.Name}</p>
    <p>{yourObject.Age}</p>
    <p>{yourObject.Address}</p>
  </div>)
)}
```